# click function disabling when another click function is clicked more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Just messing around with making a new tab page for chrome just for learning purposes. What it is doing is each time the #refresh div is clicked the background changes, then when #pin is clicked it will pin the background so it doesn't change when the page is loaded.

I have an issue where my #pin div does not call the the click function if the #refresh is clicked twice.

So what is happening currently is that if I select #pin the icon changes to a filled in heart icon (as opposed to the unpinned empty heart icon). Then when refresh is clicked it will refresh the background and change the icon back to the unpinned icon. (empty heart).

This is working though when I click #refresh while the #pin has class "glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" already then clicking #pin again does nothing

```
$("#pin").click(function() {
    var storedbg = document.getElementById('background').style.backgroundImage; 
    if($(this).hasClass("glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty")){
        $(this).removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty");
        $(this).addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-heart");
        chrome.storage.sync.set({'background' : storedbg});
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass("glyphicon glyphicon-heart")){
        $(this).removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-heart");
        $(this).addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty");
        chrome.storage.sync.clear();
    }
});

$("#refresh").click(function() {
    $('body').css({'background-image': 'url(' + background[Math.floor((Math.random() * 26) + 0)]  + ')'}); 
    chrome.storage.sync.clear();
    $('#pin').removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-heart");
    $('#pin').addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the way I wrote the removal of classes was the issue!

Managed to fix with:

```
$("#refresh").click(function() {
    $('body').css({'background-image': 'url(' + background[Math.floor((Math.random() * 26) + 0)]  + ')'}); //sets random background*/
    if ($('#pin').hasClass("glyphicon glyphicon-heart")){
        $('#pin').removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-heart");
        $('#pin').addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty");
        chrome.storage.sync.clear();
    }
});
```